# print pointers of type (int *) in a coherent way

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code in C:

```
int tab[10] = {3, 10, 5, 7, 9, 4, 9, 4, 6, 8, 0};
printf("(int*)&tab[0]=%p (int*)&tab[1]=%p (int*)&tab[1]-(int*)&tab[0]=%d\n", (int*)&tab[0], (int*)&tab[1], ((int*)&tab[1]) - ((int*)&tab[0]));
```

And it returns:

```
(int*)&tab[0]=0xbf9775c0 (int*)&tab[1]=0xbf9775c4 (int*)&tab[1]-(int*)&tab[0]=1
```

What I do not understand is that why the difference returned is 1 instead of 4 at the end. Could anyone tell me a way to print them (addresses and their difference) in a coherent way for (int *)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're doing pointer arithmetic.  And pointer arithmetic is always done in units of whatever the pointer is pointing to (which in this case is 4, because `sizeof(int) == 4` on your system).

If you want to know the difference in raw addresses, then either multiply the result of the subtraction by `sizeof(int)`, or cast the pointers to `char *` before doing the subtraction.

Comment: Or simply cast them to int before subtracting.

Comment: @Lundin: Assuming `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)`, then yes!

Comment: @Oli - I think you mean `intptr_t`, not `size_t`, in your comment.

Comment: @SoftTimur: On top of that, a plain `%d` is not a proper format specifier for printing the subtraction result. `%d` is for `int`, while the subtraction produces `ptrdiff_t`. The proper way to print it in C99 is to use `t` modifier: `%td`. In C89/90 the proper way would be to cast the result of subtraction to a "known" type, like `long long` (and use `%lld`) or `long` (and use `%ld`) or `int` (and use `%d`).

Comment: @Andrey: note that `long long`, if it exists in C89/C90, is an extension :)

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
((int *) &tab[1]) - ((int *) &tab[0])
=> &tab[1] - &tab[0]
=> (tab + 1) - tab
=> 1
```

On the other hand

```
((intptr_t) &tab[1]) - ((intptr_t) &tab[0])
=> ((intptr_t) (tab + 1)) - ((intptr_t) tab)
=> sizeof (int)
```

where intptr_t is defined in stdint.h (from the C99 standard library).